# Git: deleted files still show in pull request but not in repo

Tags: git

I have a develop branch with bunch of '.history' folder full of useless files. I deleted all of them with

```
rm -rf .history
git add .
git commit -m "cleanup: deleting .history"
git push
```

The develop branch in bitbucket and locally correctly shows no .history folder anymore.

On the other branch called develop-new there is no .history folder, but are some other changes.

But when I send a PR to merge develop-new into develop, the whole .history folder shows up again as if it wants to delete it.

How do I solve it? I can't delete it since it's not there...

Comment: Remember that *every* commit holds a *full snapshot of every file*. After deleting some files, the new snapshots just hold *fewer files*. The older snapshots, which literally cannot be changed, still hold all their files.

Comment: If you dislike the fact that some existing commits *do* have those files, you can make a whole new chain of all-new commits in which those files never get added, and therefore never need to be deleted again. When (and whether) to do this is not a *technical* question so as much as it is a *social / community* one: if others are using the commits that have the `.history/*` files, you need to have them agree to abandon those commits and start using the new ones.

Comment: `git rebase` (as in [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72697171/1256452)) is a Git power tool for copying some existing set of commits to a new-and-improved set of commits. You can do a lot of things (though not everything that can be done) with `git rebase`.

Answer (score 1):

You have added a new commit where those folder contents have been removed.

But past commits still do have those folders.

A PR from `develop-new` (no folder) to `develop` should delete those folders, assuming there was no new commits on `develop` which would have modified a `.history` folder.

Regarding your PR, try locally:

```
git fetch
git switch develop-new
git rebase origin/develop
git push --force
```

See if your PR deletes those folders then (since it is rebased on top of `origin/develop`, the target branch)

Comment: The problem is I can't just merge develop-new into develop because of other changes that need to be handled by other developers, I can't just merge them in, which is what I assume will happen if I do the above. All I want is now to have those deleted files gone from PR, because physically they aren't there at all, but PR somehow sees them - because of as you said, past commits probably.

Comment: @Ska Exactly, hence the local rebase and force push of your PR branch. Other developers will need to merge develop into their feature branch (to validate the folder deletions), and go on from there.

Comment: What if I ever the develop branch to before deletion, and then delete the .history folder with git rm?

Comment: @Ska "What if I ever the develop branch to before deletion"... I am not sure that I understand that sentence. Could you clarify it?

Comment: sorry, I meant to *revert* the develop branch to the state before deletion, and delete it again properly with git rm. Would work?

Comment: @Ska Yes, you would still need for the developers to merge develop into their feature branch to propagate that deletion.